# Radio button value check in action is true or false

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-2-metadata

I am new in MVC. I am working on a view where I add two radio buttons.

```
<label for="lDIV1">
    <input id="lDIV1" type="radio" name='rbtab' value='DIV1' onclick="javascript:custom()" />Create
    Email:</label>
<label for="lDIV2">
    <input id="lDIV2" type="radio" name='rbtab' checked="checked"  value='DIV2' onclick="javascript:defaul()" />Default
    Email:</label>
<div id='Content' style="display: block">
```

Now I want to call a function in Action {Http} that is if first radio button is true then call radiobutton1() method or else call radiobutton2() method 
Can you guys Help me out how to apply conditions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

im not sure what you want to do because your question is not that clear but here is how you can do something when a checkbox is checked with jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/HQXLm/1/

```
<input id="checkme" type="checkbox" /> click me to find out if im checked

$('#checkme').click(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')){
         alert('I am checked, do something here');   
    }
});
```